# Error Cannot cast from Query to Int

Tags: java, hql

Quiero obtener el Id de una tabla de MySql pero me salta el error "Cannot cast from Query to Int", por lo que entiendo no puedo transformar un objeto en Int?

Estoy trabajando con java IDE Eclipse, con Hibernate

"nacionalidad" es un string que llega como parámetro.

```
conexion.abrirConexion();
int idNacionalidad = (int)conexion.getSession().createQuery("SELECT nacionalidad.idNacionalidad FROM nacionalidad INNER JOIN cliente ON nacionalidad.descripcion="+nacionalidad);
conexion.cerrarSession();
```

Comment: Crear query es lo mismo que ejecutarlo? Eso que estás haciendo crea un object `Query`

Answer (score 1):

Observando la documentación de [HowToDoInJava](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/complete-hibernate-query-language-hql-tutorial/)
Lo que estás olvidando es limitar la query a un solo resultado, de modo tal que usando `query.setMaxResults(1)` limitarás el resultado a solo 1 elemento. Luego haciendo uso de `query.uniqueResult()` recibirás el único elemento devuelto. Por lo tanto tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
conexion.abrirConexion();
Query Query = conexion.getSession().createQuery("SELECT nacionalidad.idNacionalidad FROM nacionalidad INNER JOIN cliente ON nacionalidad.descripcion="+nacionalidad);

query.setMaxResults(1);
int idNacionalidad = (int) query.uniqueResult();
conexion.cerrarSession();
```

Comment: Estoy trabajando con Hibernate!

Comment: Ahí Actualicé mi respuesta :D

Comment: En todo caso si falla el casteo al dato primitivo int probá usando
`int idNacionalidad = (Integer) query.uniqueResult().intValue()`

Comment: Gracias! voy a probarlo!

Comment: ¡No olvides explicar brevemente el contenido del enlace! Piénsalo: si el enlace llega a romperse, parte de la explicación de la respuesta se perderá. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.